Define polygon using CrossingPolygon or WindingPolygon
Is it possible to define polygon using CrossingPolygon or WindingPolygon so that the result is like the first image (without red dashed lines and points)?
The polygon must be defined only by eight points in po and no other.
I tried to search through all the possible permutations by sight but have not fond the right result. I might have simply missed it because there are lots of possibilities (if we fix first point then at least 7!=5040).
But there are also two possible ways to define polygons in CrossingPolygon and three possible ways in WindingPolygon as can be seen in documentation. I am not sure which one to choose.
Maybe it is even impossible to reproduce the first image but I do not know who to check it.
The second image depicts 4 possible outcomes of CrossingPolygon.
(By the way maybe also FilledCurve could be used?)
po = Join[#*{2, 1} & /@ #, #*{1, 2} & /@ #] &@{{1, 1}, {-1, 
     1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}};
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Red, Dashed]], 
  Polygon[po[[{1, 2, 6, 5}]]], White, Polygon[po[[{1, 2, 6, 5} + 1]]],
   Black, Polygon[po[[{1, 2, 6, 5} + 2]]], White, 
  Polygon[{{2, -1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -2}}], Red, PointSize[Medium],
   Point[po]}, ImageSize -> Small]

Graphics[{CrossingPolygon[#], Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[po]}, 
   ImageSize -> Small] & /@ Table[RandomSample[po], 4]




Every point in the original set must have two segments attached to it (assuming that we're disallowing repeat "visits"). If those segments coincide, then they "disappear" from the crossing polygon. Otherwise, we'll have a filled in "corner" at each point. So, consider the two points at the upper left of your first picture. They both violate this condition. I haven't actually spent time checking if this can be made rigorous, so I didn't make it an answer. But maybe it'll prompt some useful thoughts.
